# How to change PID location of Mariadb 10.3?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am using centos7.3,install mariadb 10.3 by `yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client`.
In my.cnf,I set PID location as below:

```
[mysqld_safe]
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid
```

I can log into mariadb, and there's no error in error-log.But I cannot find `/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid`.
Even I touch `/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid` and `chown mysql:mysql`,there's nothing  in `/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid`.

Based on olegsv's answer,  PID location is `/var/lib/mysql/localhost.pid`

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like '%pid%';
+---------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                        |
+---------------+------------------------------+
| pid_file      | /var/lib/mysql/localhost.pid |
+---------------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Based on Rick James's answer, I move `pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid` to `[mysqld]` and `systemctl restart mariadb`,I found mariadb cannot restart,error information as below:

```
[root@localhost my.cnf.d]# systemctl status mariadb -l
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.10 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-10-21 1:10:12 UTC; 30s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 1502 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1610 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 1517 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1515 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1610 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 21 1:10:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.10 database server...
Oct 21 1:10:12 localhost.localdomain mysqld[1610]: 2018-10-21 1:10:12 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.10-MariaDB-log) starting as process 1610 ...
Oct 21 1:10:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 21 1:10:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.10 database server.
Oct 21 1:10:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Oct 21 1:10:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
```

And:

```
[root@localhost my.cnf.d]# journalctl -xe
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mariadb.service has begun shutting down.
Oct 21 1:10:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.10 datab
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mariadb.service has begun starting up.
Oct 21 1:10:12 localhost.localdomain mysqld[1610]: 2018-10-21 1:10:12 0 [Note]
Oct 21 1:10:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process
Oct 21 1:10:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.1
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Oct 21 1:10:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered f
Oct 21 1:10:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
Oct 21 1:10:12 localhost.localdomain polkitd[601]: Unregistered Authentication
```

How to change PID location of Mariadb 10.3?

Comment: Let's approach it from a different way...  Why do you 'need' to change the pid location?

Comment: @RickJames,at least, I need to find out why PID diff from setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `my.cnf` (or wherever the config file is), add in the `[mysqld]` section:

```
pid-file = /path/to/filename
```

Comment: In this question, `pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid` doesn't work,any reason?

Comment: You mean I should use `pit-file` instead of `pid-file`??

Comment: Make sure it is in `[mysqld]` section.

Comment: In [mysqld] section will cause mariadb cannot resart, I don't unserstand the reason.I post the error information in question.

Comment: I only revised `/etc/my.conf.d/server.cnf` ,upload this file  http://txt.do/dnfw8

Comment: Hmmm...  I would expect the `pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid` in your file to be honored.

Comment: I guess it's a bug

Comment: File a bug report with MariaDB.

Answer (score 2):

from mariadb client prompt:

```
show variables like '%pid%';
```